# How do I incrementally rotate through an array with Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

Just learning swift and wanted to rotate through an array of colors like so:

```
class ColorSwitcher
{
    let colors:String[] = ["red", "blue", "green"]
    var currIndex:Int?

    var selectedColor:String{
        return self.colors[currIndex!]
    }

    init(){
        currIndex = 0
    }

    func changeColor()
    {
        currIndex++ //this doesn't work
    }
}
```

When I try to call the function like so:

```
var switcher:ColorSwitcher = ColorSwitcher()
switcher.selectedColor // returns red

switcher.changeColor()

switcher.selectedColor // still returns red
```

The problem is with the `changeColor` function. The error I get is:

```
Could not find an overload for '++' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `currIndex` is an optional. I'd suggest refactoring like so:

```
class ColorSwitcher {
    let colors:String[] = ["red", "blue", "green"]
    var currIndex:Int = 0

    var selectedColor:String {
        return self.colors[currIndex]
    }

    func changeColor() {
        currIndex++
    }
}
```

if you want to keep it an optional you'll need to do this:

```
currIndex = currIndex! + 1
```

but of course that isn't safe, so you should probably do:

```
if let i = currIndex {
    currIndex = i + 1
}
else {
    currIndex = 1
}
```

Also, keep in mind that you don't need to use an optional if you're going to set the value in your `init()`. The following is fine:

```
class ColorSwitcher {
    let colors:String[] = ["red", "blue", "green"]
    var currIndex:Int

    init(startIndex: Int) {
        currIndex = startIndex
    }

    var selectedColor:String {
        return self.colors[currIndex]
    }

    func changeColor() {
        currIndex++
    }
}
```

Comment: and maybe `currIndex = (currIndex  + 1) %  colors.count`

Comment: @ChristianDietrich indeed, but that's a separate issue, I get the feeling this code is pared down to clarify the question (since it's of no obvious use as is)

Comment: Just practicing for rotating through a series of images using UIKit guys :)

Comment: @AmitErandole ah, yeah - you don't need to call it in this case because you don't have a superclass (fixed now)

Answer (score 1):

you can overload the missing `++` operator for optional `Int`, like e.g. this:

```
@assignment @postfix func ++(inout x: Int?) -> Int? {
    if x != nil {
        x = x! + 1
        return x
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

or you can change your class, like e.g. this:

```
class ColorSwitcher {

    let colors:String[] = ["red", "blue", "green"]
    var currIndex: Int = 0

    var selectedColor: String {
        return self.colors[currIndex]
    }

    func changeColor() {
        currIndex++
    }
}
```

*NOTE: that does not hold any improvement in your class's internal behaviour. it will do the same for you as did in your OP.*